# Let M be a simply connected smooth manifold, let D be a 1-dimensional distribution on M

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Show that there exists a vector field $V$ defined on $M$ such that $V_p$ spans $D_p$ for all $p \in M$.

I don't usually ask for "hint to start" but I am quite stumped by this problem.

The only thing I can find that's relevant, is possibly using the orientation covering or something similar for $M$, since we know that all simply connected smooth manifolds are orientable.

The orientation cover is a fiber bundle whose preimage of every point in $p$ are two orientation of $T_p M$, and I can see how we may be able to imitate the construction for the orientation cover to construct a fiber bundle from $D$ as there are only two points on $D_p$ that span $D_p$ but also have length $1$ given a Riemannian metric.

Edit: Changed $V_p \in D_p$ to $V_p$ spans $D_p$ for all $p \in M$.

Comment: As stated, there's the trivial solution, where $V_p = 0$ for every $p$. Did you forget something?

Comment: Yes of course, $V_p$ must span $D_p$, thank you.

Comment: The "relevant" thing you found is exactly what I would have suggested doing.  In more detail, if you want to avoid Riemannian metrics, consider an equivalence relation on $D\setminus\{0-section\}$ where you identify $v_p$ with $\lambda v_p$ for any $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^{>0}$.  Then prove that $(D\setminus\{0-section\}) /\sim$ is a double cover of $M$.  Or use Riemannian metric and look at the subset of $D$ consisting of unit length vectors, as you suggested.